# Question on viscosity solution through stochastic differential equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have learned that for the equation $\partial_tu+a(u)\partial_xu=0$, the entropy solution could be obtained as the limit of the equation $\partial_tu+a(u)\partial_xu=\epsilon u_{xx}$  with $\epsilon>0$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. When I study the stochastic equation, there is a connect of the stochastic equation with the classical ones.

Suppose $dX=b dt+G dW$ where $W$ is the Brownian motion. And $u(X,t)$ will follow
$du=(\partial_t u+\frac{1}{2}G^2 u_{xx}+ b u_x)dt+G u_x dW$. If we take the parameter $G=\epsilon$, $du$ will have the classical solution as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Here how could I prove the uniqueness and convergence of such a process?  Here is the limit same with the definition of viscosity solution in the traditional case? Could one provide some references for the viscosity of stochastic differential equations?

I think it easy to generalize the one dimensional case to higher dimension and I want to define the entropy solution with the help of theory of SDEs and to study the shock solution in a similar method.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the function $a$ dependent on $u$ or on $x$ only. In the former case it is not obvious to link it to stochastic differential equations easily as the PDE is not linear and your process $X_t$  will depend on $u$ which is unknown here. If $a$ depends only on $x$ you can represent it via Feyman-Kac and all what you need for the existence of the solution to the SDE equation on $X_t$ is that $a$ is Lipschitzian.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references...

@article {MR1959710,
    AUTHOR = {Lions, P.-L. and Souganidis, P. E.},
     TITLE = {Viscosity solutions of fully nonlinear stochastic partial
              differential equations},
      NOTE = {Viscosity solutions of differential equations and related
              topics (Japanese) (Kyoto, 2001)},
   JOURNAL = {S\=urikaisekikenky\=usho K\=oky\=uroku},
  FJOURNAL = {S\=urikaisekikenky\=usho K\=oky\=uroku},
    NUMBER = {1287},
      YEAR = {2002},
     PAGES = {58--65},
   MRCLASS = {60H10 (35J60 35R60)},
  MRNUMBER = {1959710},
}

@article {MR1807189,
    AUTHOR = {Lions, Pierre-Louis and Souganidis, Panagiotis E.},
     TITLE = {Uniqueness of weak solutions of fully nonlinear stochastic
              partial differential equations},
   JOURNAL = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S\'er. I Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Comptes Rendus de l'Acad\'emie des Sciences. S\'erie I.
              Math\'ematique},
    VOLUME = {331},
      YEAR = {2000},
    NUMBER = {10},
     PAGES = {783--790},
      ISSN = {0764-4442},
     CODEN = {CASMEI},
   MRCLASS = {35R60 (35A05)},
  MRNUMBER = {1807189 (2002a:35214)},
MRREVIEWER = {Marek Capi{\'n}ski},
       DOI = {10.1016/S0764-4442(00)01597-4},
       URL = {htp://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0764-4442(00)01597-4},
}

@article {MR1659958,
    AUTHOR = {Lions, Pierre-Louis and Souganidis, Panagiotis E.},
     TITLE = {Fully nonlinear stochastic partial differential equations:
              non-smooth equations and applications},
   JOURNAL = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S\'er. I Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Comptes Rendus de l'Acad\'emie des Sciences. S\'erie I.
              Math\'ematique},
    VOLUME = {327},
      YEAR = {1998},
    NUMBER = {8},
     PAGES = {735--741},
      ISSN = {0764-4442},
     CODEN = {CASMEI},
   MRCLASS = {60H15 (35R60)},
  MRNUMBER = {1659958 (99j:60095)},
MRREVIEWER = {Sergey V. Lototsky},
       DOI = {10.1016/S0764-4442(98)80161-4},
       URL = {htp://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0764-4442(98)80161-4},
}

@article {MR1647162,
    AUTHOR = {Lions, Pierre-Louis and Souganidis, Panagiotis E.},
     TITLE = {Fully nonlinear stochastic partial differential equations},
   JOURNAL = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S\'er. I Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Comptes Rendus de l'Acad\'emie des Sciences. S\'erie I.
              Math\'ematique},
    VOLUME = {326},
      YEAR = {1998},
    NUMBER = {9},
     PAGES = {1085--1092},
      ISSN = {0764-4442},
     CODEN = {CASMEI},
   MRCLASS = {60H15 (35R60)},
  MRNUMBER = {1647162 (99j:60094)},
MRREVIEWER = {Samy Tindel},
       DOI = {10.1016/S0764-4442(98)80067-0},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0764-4442(98)80067-0},
}

etc...

Comment: Could you add some more explanation of how this article answers the question?